# Date/Time differences between MySql and PHP?

Tags: php, sql, date, datetime

I have this table

```
Name                       Birth_Date            Register_Date
---------------------------------------------------------------
Ali                       1990-03-22             2010-03-1 15:1:42
Ali1                      1991-07-18             2010-03-2 12:44:2
```

When I inserted these values, I inserted the **Birth_Date** as a String such as '1990-03-22', and I used 'NOW()' for **Register_Date**.

**NOW()** will generate the current `datetime` according to the MySql Server.

Now when I try to get the time between the current date and the **Register_Date** (Time passed since he registered), I use the following:

`SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(register_date) ...`

In PHP, if I wanted to do that, I suppose I have to get the current date: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`;

My question is, is there a difference between calculating the date difference (between a date and today) via MySql or via PHP?

Currently, on my localhost (XAMPP), `CURDATE()` and `date(..)` generates the same date, but will it generate the same date for other users when my website goes online?

Comment: SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(register_date) ... Will return nothing because CURDATE() year is same as YEAR(register_date)

Comment: Then it should return 0, not nothing, should it not?

Comment: @VishwanathDalvi Ignore 2013 I was only providing an example, I changed it to 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both your mysql and PHP server are operating on the same timezone and have their clocks properly synchronized, you wont have an issue.

Comment: By default are they operating on the same timezone? and how do I make sure of this?

Comment: There is no default timezone. This is a server configuration. `mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;` will let you check the mysql timezone, `date_default_timezone_get()` in php will let you get the timezone.

Comment: I got `Europe/Berlin` in PHP (I'm not in europe).

Comment: You're going to want to fix that then. ;) SYSTEM in mysql means its using the timezone of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to upload your php website and your DB on the same server I think you'll not have problem , but If you use different servers you may have time issues.

to avoid this issue I advice you to save the time with time zone, to be able to get the correct time from any server.